# Relative memory reference issue

Tags: ios, memory

In below code, I have a Person and person have a address (right now city only).

```
class Address {
    var city : String
    init(city : String) {
        self.city = city
    }

    deinit {
        print(self.city, "deinit")
    }
}


class Person {
    var name : String
    var age : Int
    var address : Address?

    init(name: String, age: Int, address : Address?) {
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.address = address
    }

    class func createPerson( name : String, age : Int, address : Address? ) -> Person {
        let p  = Person(name: name, age: age, address: address)
        return p
    }

    deinit {
        self.address = nil
        print(self.name, " Deinit")
    }

}
```

**Issue Case 1 :**

If I create objects like this and I `nil` the person then **london** is not getting nil.

```
let london : Address? = Address(city: "London")
var jack : Person? = Person.createPerson(name: "Jack", age: 34, address: london)

jack = nil // jack de-init, london not de-init
// now london is the memory leak
```

**Issue Case 2 :**

If I declare london as weak then london deinit but if london referencing other person then its address also getting nil

```
weak var london : Address? = Address(city: "London")
var jack : Person? = Person.createPerson(name: "Jack", age: 34, address: london)
var elon : Person? = Person.createPerson(name: "Elon", age: 45, address: london)

jack = nil // jack de-init, london de-init 

print(elon?.address?.city) // nil
```

---

Is there commutative solution of this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is intended behaviour.
In your case 1, london is still referenced by the context of the method you're currently in, which is why it shouldn't be de-initialised. It's not a memory leak, london will be de-initialised when the context closes, i. e. when the method is done.

Comment: Oops, I was testing in playground and forget this stupid reason. Thanks your point is valid all the time. 